# What is a proper way to send a click using winapi messages?

Tags: java, winapi

Once you have a `hwnd` handle for a windows window, you can make it think that user pressed mouse button down using `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0)`.

I assumed that click is sent by sending mouse down and mouse up message:

```
  @Override
  public void click(int x, int y, MouseButton button, boolean isControl, boolean isAlt, boolean isShift) {
    mouseDown(x, y, button, isControl, isAlt, isShift);
    mouseUp(x, y, button, isControl, isAlt, isShift);
  }
```

But sometimes this ends up highlighting the item I wanted to use instead of activating the click event. Am I doing it wrong in general, or is it because some applications apply extra logic to click event?

Comment: The proper way is to use the automation API rather than attempting to fake input

Comment: What API are you talking about?

Comment: UI Automation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd561932(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sure, I'm on my way to delete all my project files and use this API that, according to my research, does the same things like the libraries I use.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do (big picture), anyway? Unfortunately for your sarcasm, David Hefferman's solution is the correct solution, alongside the (older) MSAA (depending on what you want to target and how) and any API provided by the program itself. Even if none of the above options are acceptable, there's a far more correct way to send input than to post messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now that this question has become a **daily occurrence** does SO have anything where people who know more than I do can set this in stone? Would the community wiki suffice?

Comment: @andlabs No matter what you do, the input faking questions will continue to come. They are unstoppable.

Comment: If this is a daily topic why there are 0 close votes for *duplicate* reason? My question was pretty straightforward and even if any API/library covers it, it must incorporate answer to my question. I'm making a scriptable automation tool.

Comment: The standard for closing question as a duplicate is actually pretty strict, someone would have to find a pretty much exact duplicate. In this case I don't think anyone can be bothered to find a possible duplicate question because you're probably not going to like its answer either.

Comment: Why would you choose to fake input, a technique that is prone to wrinkles, and shun the official platform supplied automation library? I can't think of any sane reasons to do so. Is it just stubbornness? You've written a bunch of code and can't bring yourself to throw it away? Do you want your program to work smoothly, or be a bit flaky?

Comment: If I really needed scriptable automation software, I would download some. This project has also an educational purpose. Using a library that does the whole job itself break the purpose and leaves no fun to the project. You don't know the answer so instead, you are being picky and unhelpful in the comments. If there's nothing useful you can add just move along. I don't need this.

Comment: This strikes me: You come here, asking for help with issues you have run into, you are then given established solutions (MSAA/UI Automation), only to conclude that those tools do the same that your libraries do. Apparently, the libraries you use do **not** produce the desired result. How is that the same thing as the recommended solution that does work as advertised?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure if they do or not. I'm working on that project for fun. I didn't even try to use the full potential of the Sirius library I'm using. Guys who post comments like you do have no understanding of project for fun or for educational purposes. Obviously, instead of trying to help you just as others are trying to force me to give up my project and push your own ideas on me. Why do you do so is a mystery for me though.

Comment: Your question is titled: *What is a proper way to send a click using winapi messages?* Well, the proper wat is to use the platform's native facilities. That's really all there is to it. We understand fun projects. You didn't state that in the question. Anyway, you seem to be neglecting the key message from @IInspectable. Your approach doesn't work. It's not going to work. It is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: And how is it flawed? How does the system API do it properly? I already posed this question. I really thought that all the applications get are the messages.

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally flawed, for a number of reasons. One obvious race condition is, that input from other sources can get interspersed between your calls to press and depress the mouse button. Likewise, the foreground window can change between those two input events. Sending input messages also fails to update internal state, causing API calls like `GetKeyboardState` to return unpredictable results. In all, this is not a proper way to automate an application.